# Hibernate validator NotEmpty trim issue

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

It appears that the Hibernate `NotEmpty` annotation does not result in an error for strings filled with whitespace (`"    "`).  Only works for nulls or empty strings (ie: `new String()`).  Is there a workaround/fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your @NotEmpty with a @Pattern annotation that includes a regex expression that will fail on strings that are pure whitespace or empty (you may be able to include both @NotEmpty and @Pattern and simplify the regex that way).    Or write a custom validator as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en/html_single/#validator-customconstraints).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing a custom validator.

Answer (score 15):

@NotEmpty is used to check size rather than contents and applies to Collections as well as Strings.  The functionality you're looking for is provided in @NotBlank which is specific to Strings and ignores trailing whitespace.

Comment: I wish some of the Hibernate constraints had made it into JEE6. I find the default set of JEE6 constraints somewhat limited!

Comment: Note that `@NotEmpty` was added in version 4.1. For versions before 4.1, you will need to use a custom validator or `@Pattern`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17136803/2102634 for an longer explanation.

Answer (score 9):

`@NotBlank` is the way to test string lengths with an implicit trim call.