# h:inputtext not accepting blank space when required = "true". Natural behaviour is not working as expected

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

My application was working fine and all my `h:inputText` component was accepting the blank space (As it is the valid value from the keyboard). We have deployed it in WAS8.5 and using java7. Its working fine in one of our development environment and not working on other dev, as well as our local environments. I have checked in the web.xml file for

```
<param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
```

we don't have anything specified. Can someone please let me for what reason h:inputText component is not accepting `blank Spaces`.

Comment: compare the classpaths of the environments particularly in jsf related jars

Comment: No one JSF impl/version trims spaces this way. Cause is really directly or indirectly your own code or libs. Only reasonable server side explanation is that there's a converter for String.class which trims spaces, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33241290. Other probable cause would be in client side, e.g. some JavaScript trimming all blanks on key up/press. By the way, the [jsf-1.2] tag on your question contradicts with that JSF 2.0 specific context param. What JSF version exactly are you using?

Comment: Am sorry, it was my mistake I shouldn't have posted JSF2.0 specific context param.  I'm using 1.2 version.