# Should javax.faces.convert.Converter.getAsObject modify the passed UIComponent?

Tags: jsf, converters

In a legacy code base, I came across this:

```
@javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter(forClass = java.lang.String.class)
public class WhitespaceToNullConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent c, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            if (c instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
                ((EditableValueHolder) c).setSubmittedValue(null);
            }
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

First, isn't the passed `UIComponent` always an `EditableValueHolder`? Is that check needed?

Second, should a `Converter` change the `UIComponent` it's called for? That seems odd to me, assuming that the component's value is probably used to populate the `UIComponent` anyway.

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) doesn't say anything in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *First, isn't the passed UIComponent always an EditableValueHolder?*

Normally, `getAsObject()` is only called when JSF needs to convert a submitted value to a model value. Normally, this is only called in `UIInput#validate()`. And `UIInput` implements `EditableValueHolder`. So, assuming normal circumstances, the answer to this specific question is "Yes".

---

> *Is that check needed?*

No, but it is not a "bad practice" either. It was likely written by a defensive programmer who just wanted to avoid questions popping up when one abuses the converter for a purpose it wasn't designed for ;)

---

> *Second, should a Converter change the UIComponent it's called for?*

Depends on the purpose of the change. Usually indeed not, programmatically manipulating the JSF component tree from user code on is a poor practice, but sometimes there's simply no other way and then you have to hack around.

---

> *That seems odd to me, assuming that the component's value is probably used to populate the UIComponent anyway.*

This specific converter solves two separate problems as described in following related questions:

- [h:inputText which is bound to String property is submitting empty string instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-string-property-is-submitting-empty-string-instead)
- [How to prevent spaces form JSF h:inputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233398/how-to-prevent-spaces-form-jsf-hinputtext).

Only strange thing here is that the `setSubmittedValue(null)` solution to the first problem is JSF 1.x specific while the application is apparently using JSF 2.x, as evidenced by presence of `@FacesConverter`. It's most likely overlooked during a previous JSF 1.x to 2.x migration. In JSF 2.x the `setSubmittedValue(null)` task of this specific converter can entirely be replaced by below context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

That should make the converter not to look hacky anymore.

#### See also:

- [The empty String madness](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html).